# PrestaShop - confirm payment and accept order

Tags: php, payment, redirect, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I'm work on payment module in presta 1.6. It's almost done but i stoped on order-confirmation step. If i redirect to confirmation page just after validateOrder() then everything works, order-history displays and order is right status but...

finally i want to use payment gateway on external domain. I wan to redirect to url with parametrs, it will contain (coded in token) url to back presta in case of successfuly payment but...

when i use url like order-confirmation, then session expired and cart is empty so order can't be confirm.

> $success_url = PS_BASE_URI . 'order-confirmation.php?id_cart=' .
>   $id_cart . '&id;_module=' . intval($tpg_deposit->id) . '&id;_order=' .
>   intval($tpg_deposit->currentOrder);

This url works fine but ONLY when i do not leave prestashop domain. When i redirect to payment webpage, then back to presta by this url results presta 404 error, and cart is empty.

> "This page is not available"

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late, but how about:

```
$success_url = Tools::redirectLink(PS_BASE_URI . 'order-confirmation.php?id_cart=' . $id_cart . '&id;_module=' . intval($tpg_deposit->id) . '&id;_order=' . intval($tpg_deposit->currentOrder) . '&key=' . $this->context->customer->secure_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

first things that I see, possible wrong return url, your version will looks like:

```
/order_confirmation.php?{parameters}
```

there is should be something like:

```
$success_url = $this->context->shop->getBaseUrl() . _MODULE_DIR_. $this->name . 'order_confirmation.php?{parameters}'
// will create
// http://yourdomain.com/modules/yourmodule/order_confirmation.php?{parameters}
```

Answer (score 0):

The validateOrder() create Order and remove Cart session. If you use an external domain, use OrderStatus like 'Awaiting payment' and update it when user come back.